# How to stop sorting by id when @ngrx EntityAdapter

Tags: angular, ngrx

Here is my adapter:

`const adapter: EntityAdapter<SampleModel> = createEntityAdapter<SampleModel>();`

and here is the reducer:

```
adapter.addMany(action.payload.samples, {
                ...initialSamplesState,
                totalCount: action.payload.totalCount,
                listLoading: false,
                lastQuery: action.payload.page,
                showInitWaitingMessage: false
            });
```

My model has an `id` field and the adapter is sorting the HTTP response array by `id` automatically. I would like to know how I can stop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, it's JavaScript that does this.

You can sort entities with the [`sortComparer`](https://ngrx.io/api/entity/EntityAdapter#sortComparer) method on the adapter.

```
export function sortByName(a: User, b: User): number {
  return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<User> = createEntityAdapter<User>({
  sortComparer: sortByName,
});
```

See the [docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/adapter) for more info.